# OSX service erroneously found in archive

Tags: xcode, macos, service

I am developing an OSX app that advertises a service, to act on files selected in Finder. If the app is running, it works as it should. However, when the app is not running and the service is invoked from Finder, it fires up not the installed version in /Applications, but an old version archived with XCode (eg at `/Users/sgvd/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2012-08-18/MyApp 18-08-2012 13.25.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp`). This stops me from properly testing my app, and I asume it can break it for users as well when multiple copies of the app are around.

When I run `/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs -dump_pboard` the NSBundlePath entry of the service does point to the correct location in /Applications.

Is there a way to edit the Info.plist to ensure the installed version is started? Or is there a way to at least ensure a certain version is executed, perhaps through the NSPortName entry? And finally, is there any predefined search order to find the app, or can I define it in the Info.plist or build settings of my app, eg is it well defined what happens if there is both a version in /Applications and in ~/Applications?

Comment: I am not sure as to why my question is closed. I feel it fits these points mentioned in the FAQ:

- a specific programming problem (how do I make my program so that the right version is opened when firing its service)

- software tools commonly used by programmers (if the answer is to change some settings in XCode to not add programs in the Archives location to the service resolution path)

- practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession (I feel it is practical and answerable, and can't imagine this being relevant outside of the programming profession)